# Checkbox default icon doesn’t update with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a simple script that on `<a>` click it checks or unchecks a checkbox. All works fine the first time, but once the value is altered with jQuery it’s not being updated (though in Chrome’s inspector the attribute `checked="checked"` is being added/removed).

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="js-tick-untick-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="send-invite-checkbox" />
    Something something in the month of May
</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.js-tick-untick-checkbox').click(function() {
  var checkbox = $(this).find('.send-invite-checkbox');

  if ($(checkbox).attr('checked') === 'checked') {
    checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).removeClass('selected-element');
  } else {
    checkbox.attr('checked', 'checked');
    $(this).addClass('selected-element');
  }
  return false;
})
```

Check out the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y3e0jfc6/

I tried various other options, like `checked="true"` / `checked="false"`, none work…

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

From [docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> As of jQuery 1.6, the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the **checked**, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.

```
$('.js-tick-untick-checkbox').click(function () {
    var checkbox = $(this).find('.send-invite-checkbox');
    if ($(checkbox).prop('checked')) {
        checkbox.prop('checked', false);
        $(this).removeClass('selected-element');
    } else {
        checkbox.prop('checked', true);
        $(this).addClass('selected-element');
    }
    return false;
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/y3e0jfc6/3/)

*Sidenote: you can do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/y3e0jfc6/5/) as well.*

Comment: Thanks, should’ve used `prop()`.

Comment: @ TJ, I will suggest use `checkbox.prop('checked', true);` instead of checkbox.prop('checked', `true`);

Comment: @AmitAgrawal did you mean the quotes around true..? i prefer boolean also… updated...

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `$.prop()` instead.

```
checkbox.prop('checked', true);
checkbox.prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$('.js-tick-untick-checkbox').click(function() {
  var checkbox = $(this).find('.send-invite-checkbox');

    if ($(checkbox).is(':checked')) {
    checkbox.prop('checked', false);
    $(this).removeClass('selected-element');
  } else {
    checkbox.prop('checked', true);
    $(this).addClass('selected-element');
  }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use *.prop* instead of *.attr*

updated jquery

```
$('.js-tick-untick-checkbox').click(function() {
var checkbox = $(this).find('.send-invite-checkbox');

if ($(checkbox).prop('checked') == true) {
checkbox.prop('checked', false);
$(this).removeClass('selected-element');
} else {
checkbox.prop('checked', true);
$(this).addClass('selected-element');
}
return false;
})
```

Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the scope of attr. [Source](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: this is also suggested by TN. Any difference

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.js-tick-untick-checkbox').click(function() {
  var checkbox = $(this).find('.send-invite-checkbox'); 
    if ($(checkbox).is(':checked')) {
    $(checkbox).removeAttr('checked');
  } else {
    $(checkbox).prop('checked', 'checked');       
  }
   $(this).toggleClass('selected-element');
  return false;
})
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/4ywmLr3u/1/